# RTSP Stream xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rtsp

I am trying to play an 30 seconds rtsp video in an ios app build in xcode 12.5. Unfortunately i could not find a way to do this. Could anyone give me a plugin or a way to handle this?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Comment: give it a try: https://github.com/stevenwuzheng/RtspPlayer-iOS

Answer (score 0):

Try VLCKit/MobileVLCKit for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is kinda old question, but I also found this issue, and there is not too much data out there...

As Dmytro pointed out MobileVLCKit is the best option out there.

I implemented it using swiftui for the interface, so firstly I have to create a UIViewRepresentable to display the stream view

Firstly import MobileVLCKit

```
struct VlcPlayerRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable{ //MARK: Transform from a UIView into swiftUI compatible
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<VlcPlayerRepresentable>) {
}

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    return PlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
}}
```

Then initiate the Player

```
class PlayerUIView: UIView, VLCMediaPlayerDelegate,ObservableObject{
let mediaPlayer : VLCMediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()// You can also add options in here
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: UIScreen.screens[0].bounds)
    let url = URL(string: "rtsp://rtspURLString:8554/live")!//replace your resource here
    
    let media = VLCMedia(url: url)
        
    media.addOptions([// Add options here
        "network-caching": 300,
        "--rtsp-frame-buffer-size":100,
        "--vout": "ios",
        "--glconv" : "glconv_cvpx",
        "--rtsp-caching=": 150,
        "--tcp-caching=": 150,
        "--realrtsp-caching=": 150,
        "--h264-fps": 20.0,
        "--mms-timeout": 60000
    ])
    
    mediaPlayer.media = media
    mediaPlayer.delegate = self
    mediaPlayer.drawable = self
    mediaPlayer.audio.isMuted = true
   
    mediaPlayer.videoAspectRatio = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: ("16:9" as NSString).utf8String)
    mediaPlayer.play()}


func checkConnection() -> Bool{
    let isPlaying: Bool = mediaPlayer.isPlaying
    return isPlaying
}

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }


  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }}
```

And then just add the representable view to a structure, now you can add this structure to wherever you want to display the stream.

```
struct VideoViewStructure: View {
var body: some View {
    return VStack{
        VlcPlayerRepresentable()
    }
}}
```